# How can I implement x[i][j] = y[i+j] efficiently in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Let **x** be a matrix with a shape of (A,B) and **y** be an array with a size of A+B-1.

```
for i in range(A):
    for j in range(B):
        x[i][j] = y[i+j]
```

How can I implement equivalent code efficiently using functions in numpy?

Comment: looks like `y.reshape` is what you're after, this is basically just converting a 1D array to a 2D one.

Comment: Generally, you want to use `x[i,j]` rather than `x[i][j]` for faster element access with numpy arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Approach #1** Using [`Scipy's hankel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html) -

```
from scipy.linalg import hankel

x = hankel(y[:A],y[A-1:]
```

**Approach #2** Using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
x = y[np.arange(A)[:,None] + np.arange(B)]
```

**Approach #3** Using `NumPy strides technique` -

```
n = y.strides[0]
x = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(y, shape=(A,B), strides=(n,n))
```

---

Runtime test -

```
In [93]: def original_app(y,A,B):
    ...:     x = np.zeros((A,B))
    ...:     for i in range(A):
    ...:         for j in range(B):
    ...:             x[i][j] = y[i+j]
    ...:     return x
    ...: 
    ...: def strided_method(y,A,B):
    ...:     n = y.strides[0]
    ...:     return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(y, shape=(A,B), strides=(n,n))
    ...: 

In [94]: # Inputs
    ...: A,B = 100,100
    ...: y = np.random.rand(A+B-1)
    ...: 

In [95]: np.allclose(original_app(y,A,B),hankel(y[:A],y[A-1:]))
Out[95]: True

In [96]: np.allclose(original_app(y,A,B),y[np.arange(A)[:,None] + np.arange(B)])
Out[96]: True

In [97]: np.allclose(original_app(y,A,B),strided_method(y,A,B))
Out[97]: True

In [98]: %timeit original_app(y,A,B)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.29 ms per loop

In [99]: %timeit hankel(y[:A],y[A-1:])
10000 loops, best of 3: 114 µs per loop

In [100]: %timeit y[np.arange(A)[:,None] + np.arange(B)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 60.5 µs per loop

In [101]: %timeit strided_method(y,A,B)
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.4 µs per loop
```

Additional ways based on `strides` -

It seems `strides` technique has been used at few places : [`extract_patches`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html) and [`view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) that are being used in such image-processing based modules. So, with those, we have two more approaches -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches

x = extract_patches(y,(B))
x = view_as_windows(y,(B))

In [151]: np.allclose(original_app(y,A,B),extract_patches(y,(B)))
Out[151]: True

In [152]: np.allclose(original_app(y,A,B),view_as_windows(y,(B)))
Out[152]: True

In [153]: %timeit extract_patches(y,(B))
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.4 µs per loop

In [154]: %timeit view_as_windows(y,(B))
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 µs per loop
```

Comment: The stride*trick* seems to have gone out of style here on SO, I sometimes see comments that it is not as *efficient* as it is touted to be - but for a rolling window it works great.

Comment: @wwii Exactly! In fact this is my first answer with it, getting a handle on it and it's amazing for windowed operations I think, specially with its efficiency part.

Comment: sci-kit learn has ```extract_patches()``` that uses it, and there is a generic n-d function that I like at [Efficient Overlapping Windows with Numpy](http://www.johnvinyard.com/blog/?p=268)

Comment: @wwii Was pretty interesting page that one! Also, we have `view_as_windows` from `skimage`. Incorporated both into the post. Thanks!