# Creating an identity Matrix containing diagonally determined values

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

Essentially, I'm looking for an efficient piece of code to generate the following matrix:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]
 [2 3 4 5 6]
 [3 4 5 6 7]
 [4 5 6 7 8]
 [5 6 7 8 9]]
```

I came up with the following, which works, but it's not particularly pretty, and I was thinking there's probably a way to really utilize `numpy` for this (beyond just creating the matrix and pretty-printing it):

```
import copy
import numpy as np

identity_count = 5
priority_matrix = np.identity(identity_count, dtype=int)

rating_start = 1
maximum_rating = identity_count * 2
rating_range = range(rating_start, maximum_rating)

priority_copy = copy.copy(priority_matrix)

for row_idx, row in enumerate(priority_copy):
    rating_pos = 0
    for col_idx, item in enumerate(row):
        priority_matrix[row_idx][col_idx] = rating_range[rating_pos]
        rating_pos += 1
    rating_start += 1
    rating_range = range(rating_start, maximum_rating)

print(np.matrix(priority_matrix))
```

There has to be a more efficient way of doing this (doesn't need to be with `numpy`).

Thank you!

Comment: Not a `numpy` method but you could do `matrix = [[x for x in range(y,y+5)] for y in range(1,6)]`

Comment: @roganjosh, why did you post this as a comment? It's a brilliant one-liner. I urge you to put this as an Answer.

Comment: I assumed you wanted something with numpy, I'll post now :)

Comment: Very similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22970716 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/39426690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in a simple one-liner with a list comprehension. I'm afraid that I don't know a `numpy`-specific way of doing this, but you could always convert to an array afterwards.

`matrix = [[x for x in range(y,y+5)] for y in range(1,6)]`

Answer (score 4):

You're apparently describing a type of [Hankel matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html).

```
>>> from scipy.linalg import hankel
>>> hankel(c=range(1,6), r=range(5,10))
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

The Hankel matrix has constant anti-diagonals.  The arguments `c` and `r` specify the *first column* and the *last row*, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using [`NumPy strides`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) -

```
a = np.arange(1,10)
W = 5              # Row length / Window size
nrows = a.size - W + 1
n = a.strides[0]
out = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a,shape=(nrows,W),strides=(n,n))
```

Another way with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
np.arange(10-W)[:,None] + np.arange(1,W+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing out another numpy-based option:

```
In [21]: np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5) - np.arange(0, 20, 4)[np.newaxis].T
Out[21]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

or generalized to an arbitrary size:

```
In [29]: N = 10

In [30]: np.arange(N**2).reshape(N,N) - np.arange(0, N*(N-1), N-1)[np.newaxis].T + 1
Out[30]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? using `map` and `np.vstack`

```
N = 5
x = np.arange(1,2*N)
np.vstack(map(lambda i: np.roll(x, -i), range(N)))[:,0:N]
```