# What will be the best approach for a digit like pattern in python?

Tags: python

i was trying a pattern in Python
if n == 6

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 1
3 4 5 1 2
4 5 1 2 3
5 1 2 3 4
```

after trying to think a lot
i did it like this --->

```
n = 6

for i in range(1,n):
    x = 1
    countj = 0
    for j in range(i,n):
        countj +=1
        print(j,end=" ")
        if j == n-1 and countj < n-1 :
            while countj < n-1:
                print(x , end =" ")
                countj +=1
                x +=1
        
    print()
```

but i don't think it is the best approach, I was trying to search some better approach , but not able to get the proper one, So that I came here,, **is there any possible better approach for the problem?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would do like this, using a rotating [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instance:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> n = 6
>>> d = deque(range(1, n))
>>> for _ in range(1, n):
...     print(*d)
...     d.rotate(-1)
... 
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 1
3 4 5 1 2
4 5 1 2 3
5 1 2 3 4
```

There is a similar/shorter code possible just using range slicing, but maybe it's a bit harder to understand how it works:

```
>>> ns = range(1, 6)
>>> for i in ns:
...     print(*ns[i-1:], *ns[:i-1])
... 
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 1
3 4 5 1 2
4 5 1 2 3
5 1 2 3 4
```

You could also create a mathematical function of the coordinates, which might look something like this:

```
>>> for row in range(5):
...     for col in range(5):
...         print((row + col) % 5 + 1, end=" ")
...     print()
... 
1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 1 
3 4 5 1 2 
4 5 1 2 3 
5 1 2 3 4
```

A too-clever way using list comprehension:

```
>>> r = range(5)
>>> [[1 + r[i - j - 1] for i in r] for j in reversed(r)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 1],
 [3, 4, 5, 1, 2],
 [4, 5, 1, 2, 3],
 [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

[more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.circular_shifts) has this function:

```
>>> from more_itertools import circular_shifts
>>> circular_shifts(range(1, 6))
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
 (2, 3, 4, 5, 1),
 (3, 4, 5, 1, 2),
 (4, 5, 1, 2, 3),
 (5, 1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.cycle` to make the sequence generated from `range` repeat itself, and then use `itertools.islice` to slice the sequence according to the iteration count:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
n = 6
for i in range(n - 1):
    print(*islice(cycle(range(1, n)), i, i + n - 1))
```

This outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 1
3 4 5 1 2
4 5 1 2 3
5 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 'pattern' is actually known as a Hankel matrix, commonly used in linear algebra.

So there's a [scipy function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html) for creating them.

```
from scipy.linalg import hankel
hankel([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

or

```
from scipy.linalg import hankel
import numpy as np

def my_hankel(n):
    x = np.arange(1, n)
    return hankel(x, np.roll(x, 1))

print(my_hankel(6))
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]
 [2 3 4 5 1]
 [3 4 5 1 2]
 [4 5 1 2 3]
 [5 1 2 3 4]]
```

Comment: Related: [Creating an identity Matrix containing diagonally determined values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496902/674039)

Comment: Note that *all* Hankel matrices are symmetric, by definition. I’m not sure if there is a special name for this particular kind.. maybe a “Latin square” Hankel??  :)

Comment: @wim Good point.  I changed it’s name.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing lots of answers involving Python libraries. If you want a simple way to do it, here it is.

```
n = 5
arr = [[1 + (start + i) % n for i in range(n)] for start in range(n)]
arr_str = "\n".join(" ".join(str(cell) for cell in row) for row in arr)
print(arr_str)
```